# Dart: DoubleLinkedQueue length after entry prepend

Tags: dart, queue

I'm manipulating entries inside a DoubleLinkedQueue via the DoubleLinkedQueueElement.append/prepend methods. This results in the new elements being inserted into the queue, but fails to update the length, and the toList() method results in an error being thrown.

I understand queues are only supposed to have elements added at the start/end, but it looks like the interface should allow for adding in the middle via the entries. I find it hard to believe such a common/well understood data structure would have a bug at this point - so am I using DoubleLinkedQueues incorrectly? Is there another data structure that I should be using? I'm looking to merge values from another iterable into my own sorted iterable - a SplayTreeSet might get me there in n log n time, but a simple merge should get me there in linear time...

Example of code that acts unexpectedly:

```dart
main() {
  var q = new DoubleLinkedQueue<int>.from([1]);
  q.firstEntry().prepend(0);
  print('length: ${q.length}');
  int i = 0;
  for (var qi in q){
    print('${i++}: $qi');
  }
}
```

Output:

```dart
length: 1
0: 0
1: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the length getter is only pointing to an internal counter. This is done because counting the elements everytime might take very long for long lists.

The internal counter is only updated if you use the methods that directly operate on the list instead of using the prepend method of an element. In your example you should use `q.addFirst(0);` which results in the length being updates. The `.prepend()` method just inserts a new element and changes the pointer. Which results in correct traversation of the elements, but the counter is wrong anyway.

Unfortunately it looks like you cannot insert elements in the middle of the list, nor can you make the list recount the elements. You should consider creating a bug over at www.dartbug.com.

// Update:

`toList()` throws an error because there are more elements than `length`.

Comment: Alas, I feared as much. Issue created at http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22802&thanks=22802&ts=1426143440 . Guess I'll hack together something that does it myself...

Comment: Bug was filed as http://dartbug.com/22802 and I'm looking into it. I think it's safe to say that the `DoubleLinkedQueue` and `DoubleLinkedQueueEntry` interfaces were missed when cleaning up before the 1.0 release, and likely haven't been looked at since then.